# How can I split multiple text string where every date in a row is assigned for every id?

Tags: powerquery

I tried to split using custom delimiter per column. I cannot figure out how can I split both column at once because every date in a row is assigned for every user id. I need to split it in a row.

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste data as an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
RemoveExtraCharacter = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"dates", each Text.Remove(_,{"]","[","}","{",""""}), type text}, {"user_id", each Text.Remove(_,{"]","[","}","{",""""}), type text}}),
#"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(RemoveExtraCharacter),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Transposed Table", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transposed Table"), Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Merged Columns", "Merged", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv)),
#"Transposed Table1" = Table.Transpose(#"Split Column by Delimiter"),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Transposed Table1",{{"Column1", type date}})
in  #"Changed Type"
```

[image]